# Construct confusion matrix with missing data

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I am constructing a confusion matrix with 4 classes (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0)

However, in some cases, the expected and predicted arrays both only have 3 classes:

```
>> expected
array([ 3.,  2.,  4.])
>> predicted
array([4.0, 2.0, 3.0])
```

So, the resulting confusion matrix only has 3x3 matrix:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
confusion_matrix(expected, predicted)

array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1]])
```

How can I still make a 4x4 confusion matrix in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. If you use the labels keyword argument, you can print a confusion matrix for all your classes.

```
>>>confusion_matrix(expected,predicted,labels=[1.,2.,3.,4.])
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

A helpful link is [confusion_matrix docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html#sklearn-metrics-confusion-matrix)